# how to use proxy on youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I wanna use the proxy and run this
`youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080`

this is an error below

`Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]`

`youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.`

what is the problem here?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming. Try superuser. Or reading the error message, which seems quite clear. (You want to use a proxy … to do what?)

Comment: I thought this will set the proxy, then I can download. Do you mean I should add the url following the  `...1080 ` ?

Answer (score 54):

The option `--proxy ...` just applies to that invocation of youtube-dl. To download a video using a proxy, add the video URL to the command line, like this:

```
youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080  https://youtu.be/BaW_jenozKc
```

If you want to use a proxy for all further invocations, create a [configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) with the contents

```
--proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Comment: for clash user: change 1080 to 7890（ 7890 is clash's default port）

Answer (score 2):

How to download video and Playlist from youtube using youtube-dl

Step 1. Download exe file from https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

I used the following command to download in windows 8.1

E:>youtube-dl.exe -proxy https://10.20.30.10:8080 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=xx

Network Options:

```
--proxy URL                      Use the specified HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS proxy.
                                 To enable SOCKS proxy, specify a proper
                                 scheme. For example
                                 socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/. Pass in an empty
                                 string (--proxy "") for direct connection
--socket-timeout SECONDS         Time to wait before giving up, in seconds
--source-address IP              Client-side IP address to bind to
-4, --force-ipv4                 Make all connections via IPv4
-6, --force-ipv6                 Make all connections via IPv6
```